# Handle "Slice Struct" properly? (golang)

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have created a Slice Struct.
But why can't I append or output values?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Slicestruct []struct {
    num      []int
    emptynum []int
}

func main() {
    slicestruct := &Slicestruct{
        {[]int{1, 2, 3}, []int{}},
        {[]int{4, 5, 6}, []int{}},
    }

    // is working:
    fmt.Println(slicestruct)

    // isn't working:
    fmt.Println(slicestruct[0].num[0])

    // isn't working:
    slicestruct[0].emptynum = append(slicestruct[0].emptynum, 99)
}
```

The error message is: "invalid operation: slicestruct[0] (type *Slicestruct does not support indexing)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer before getting an element

```golang
(*slicestruct)[0]
```

Since it's the actual slice you're accessing an element from, not the pointer.
For pointers to arrays (not slices as you have here), this step would be done automatically.

Here's a related question about pointers to slices and arrays: [Pointer to slice and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242018/pointer-to-slice-and-array)

Alternatively, you can remove the `&` when declaring your variable to make it not a pointer type. In the short sample we've seen here, there's nothing to necessitate a pointer. In general, legitimate uses of pointers to slices types are rare.

Comment: With your explanation i finally understood. Thank you for your help.